# Toggling 2nd pane data within a Multiple Series Highcharts Chart

Tags: json, highcharts, pane

I wanted to know if anyone has had success with creating a multiple series Highcharts (Highstock) chart with a second pane, that allows the user the click on a series in the 1st pane to toggle the data displayed in the second pane. An example would be:

Equity curve of both 'goog' and 'aapl' displayed in 1st pane of multi-series chart.  Volume for only 'goog' is displayed below in 2nd pane.  If the equity curve of 'aapl' is selected in 1st pane, the 2nd pane would toggle to 'aapl' volume.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a demo which should be a good guideline how to implement a function which will hide/show series in the other chart by clicking on the series in the main chart.

```
function hideSeries(current) {
  let series = chart1.series.find(s => s.name === current.name);

  if (series.visible) {
    series.hide();
  } else {
    series.show();
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/un3hk1q6/)

Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Thank you! This is getting closer to what I was trying to achieve.  

My desire is to only show one volume chart at a time, however.

Is it possible to disable the ‘hide’ feature when I click/select a price chart, and instead show the corresponding volume in the 2nd pane when the price chart is clicked? This would probably also mean highlighting the ‘selected’ price chart.

Lastly, I’d like to sync the time periods for the price charts and volume.  If the price chart displays 1 month, so would the volume.  This would assume a common navigator for both panes.

Thank you again!

Comment: I don't know what do you had in mind by saying 'highlighting', so I prepared an example where after clicking the line width is changing. By using update feature you can change actually everything in wanted series.
API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

To get a sync time periods you can use afterSetExtremes and setExtremes features. 

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/m9w2fvrc/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: I am glad that I could help. You can vote and accept the answer.

Comment: Sure thing---one final question though, if both test 1 and test 2 show up in the 1st pane (as they do in your example), can I set the 2nd pane to only show the corresponding test 1 data unless test 2 is clicked in the 1st pane, which would then toggle the test 1 data to test 2 in the 2nd pane? Thanks again!

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ryfm03q2/1/ ?

Comment: ah, exactly! Thanks again, super helpful!